# How to create facebook database diagram on small scale

Tags: database, database-design, diagram, class-diagram, erd

How to create a Facebook database on small scale.

**about the project:**

1. User can signup and create a account (info is store in UserTB table)
2. User can edit there profile & address informaion (info is store in ProfileTB & addressTB tables)
3. User can add their family member information. But Family member is Not a user of this application.
4. Family Member can become a member of application but doesnt has to be

**Issue:** How can user add their family member information (sister/brother/dad)? User's family will also have first_name, address etc.. so maybe doesnt make sense to re-creating FamilyProfile or FamilyAddress Tables. Main issue is user can add their many Family Member but family member doesnt has to be a user of this application.

```
UserTB = track user login information
ProfileTB = Track user profile information
AddressTB = track user address information
FamilyTB =  user have multi family member linked to user table (Relationship is string, ex brother, sister, dad etc..).
```

I solove this issue by adding `Linked_ID` in each tables. but it has its own issues, for example. i could have 50 tables... and when family member becomes a user... than I will have to update user_ID in 50 different tables...
[Table and test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PfB3.png)

[click here to see ERD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQUQ5.png)

Answer (score 1):

The *AddressTB* is unnecessary and must be merged with the *ProfileTB*. I know why you seperated *Street* into a different table (Normalization) but streets are just way too many and they can sometimes have multiple names (In some countries atleast), people can also have typos when entering their *Street* name and it's not worth it!

On the other hand you need the *FamilyTB* (I would rename this table to *RelationTB* for more clearance).The actual information for users are stored in *ProfileTB* and only their relations are stored in *FamilyTB*. (Read more [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-types-of-relations/))

Also, Family_ID cannot be a primary key on its own! Because primary keys must be **Unique**; However, a user can have multiple brothers and that violates this rule. Change it the following so it's always unique:

```
Table = FamilyTB
Field = Family_ID (PK)
Field = User_ID (PK)
Field = Relationship
```

Comment: Thanks. I am bit confused about `User_ID` beeing PK in `FamilyTB`. Shouldnt I link `User_ID` so that a User can have many Family Members. If I make `User_ID` PK, than wouldnt that make it one to one relationship? I will read the link you have me. maybe I missed something

Comment: do you thinking adding `Linked_id` a good idea?

Comment: @Xin, Both User_ID and Family_ID must be primary keys (think of it as a tuple), this way it's guaranteed to be unique.